# How to assign an integer value to an ArrayList of String elements?

Tags: java, android, particle-swarm

I have an `ArrayList` of string elements that the user enters in the `MainActivity` of my application (Android Studio). It is called `ArrayList<String>` `serviceNames`. The service names can be anything like Facebook, Fitness App, Clock App etc. I want to assign an Integer value to each of these user inputs of services as I am working on a fitness function to do with Swarm Particle algorithm.

```
public class CustomServiceSelection implements Goodness {

    public static final int numOfServices = MainActivity.servicenames.size();
    public static final int NUM_DIMENSIONS = 2 + numOfServices;
    public static final int DATA = 0;
    public static final int WLAN = 1; //get the names of the services from the arraylist
    //then convert them into an integer for the bits/no_dimensions


    boolean alwaysOn = MainActivity.costUTILITY.contains(100.0);


    ArrayList<String> serviceNames = MainActivity.servicenames;
    ArrayList<Double> costData = MainActivity.costDATA;
    ArrayList<Double> costWlan = MainActivity.costWLAN;
    ArrayList<Double> costUtilities = MainActivity.costUTILITY;
    private double batteryCost;
    //ArrayList<Double> battery = MainActivity.costBattery;

    public CustomServiceSelection(double batteryCost, ArrayList<Double> costData, ArrayList<Double> costWlan,
                                  ArrayList<Double> costUtilities) {
        if (costUtilities == null || costUtilities.size() < 1 || costData.size() < 1 || costWlan.size() < 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Please add atleast 1 cost to Data, WLAN and Utility");
        }
        this.batteryCost = batteryCost; //make sure you add battery field to UI, user enters battery level
        this.costData = costData;
        this.costWlan = costWlan;
        this.costUtilities = costUtilities;
        //this.services = services;
    }

    public double getGoodness(boolean[] bits) {
        double utility = 0.0;
        double rcost = 0.0;
        ArrayList<Double> resourceCost = new ArrayList<Double>();

        for(Double i : costData){

        }

        for (int x = 0; x <= NUM_DIMENSIONS; x++) { //for each resource that is a bit
            if (bits[x] == alwaysOn) {  //if a utility cost of a service is 100, return -2000.0
                return -2000;
            }

            if (bits[DATA] && bits[WLAN]) {
                return -500;
            }
            if (!bits[DATA] || bits[WLAN]) {
                return -450; //particle goodness always returns this??
            }
            if (bits[DATA]) {
                resourceCost = costData;
            } else if (bits[WLAN]) {
                resourceCost = costWlan;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_DIMENSIONS; i++) { //for each service the user enters
                if (bits[i]) {
                    utility += costUtilities.get(i);
                    rcost += resourceCost.get(i);
                }
            }
            if (rcost < batteryCost) {
                return utility;
            }


        }
        return utility * 0.50;
    }
    }
```

I want the num_dimensions to be 2 (WLAN and DATA) plus the number of services the user enters in the main activity. So if they enter 4 services, then 6 dimensions altogether.Then I want to assign an 'int' value to these services like this...

```
   public static final int Facebook = 2;
   public static final int Twitter = 3;
   public static final int ClockApp = 4;
```

When that is done, I want to pass it onto the `getGoodness()` function which will take these values as bits in the number of dimensions, so Facebook will be the 3rd bit in the dimensions. Any help or advice would be great, I m a uni student undertaking this as a project.

EDIT: I have now implemented a hashmap in the getGoodness() function. My code now looks like this...

```
    public double getGoodness(boolean[] bits) {
    double utility = 0.0;
    double rcost = 0.0;
    ArrayList<Double> resourceCost = new ArrayList<Double>();

    for(int i = 2; i <= NUM_DIMENSIONS; i++) { //hashmap that stores the   service names with an int value
        for(int k = 0; k <= numOfServices; k++) {
            serviceMap.put(i, serviceNames.get(k));
        }
```

I need the first 2 bits of NUM_DIMENSIONS to be WLAN and DATA. So for each service the user enters, the integer value assigned to them goes up by 1 starting at 2. So... (2, Facebook), (3, Twitter), (4, Uber) etc. Now my next problem is, passing these down to the getGoodness() function, I have an arraylist from the main UI activity that takes a utility(priority) cost from 0-100 of each service. This is called costUtilities, I want the bits that contain a utility of 80.0-100.0 (double) to return me a value of -2000 if it isn't on. If you can help with this, that would be great, if not, thank you for the help you've given so far, and wish me luck in my final year individual project on PSO :)

Comment: you can use normal java array and add 2 to the index...or if you do not know the size then you can use a [java.util.hashmap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to store the services with key as their int value

Comment: One more thing, you want to pass an integer array to getGoodness but it takes a boolean array. That won't work.

Comment: I've been told to use a hashmap, however it isn't my strongest point in Java. Would you be able to show me an example of how I can do that? Because in my main activity, I stored the user input in a string ArrayList.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari Not exactly, I want to assign an int value to the string elements in the array, so if there is an element called Facebook in the arraylist that is string, I want to get that out of the arraylist and assign an int value. I think a good data structure would suffice but not sure how to implement. Thank you tho

Comment: Store the inputs in a HashMap. Google HashMap you will get many tutorials. [Here](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/) is a good example for a beginner in HashMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i told in my comment you can use [java.util.hashmap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for this.

```
HashMap<int,String> serviceMap = new HashMap<int,String>
//for adding values to a hashmap
serviceMap.put(3,"facebook");
```

or if you have taken services as an arraylist **serviceNames** then you can put it afterwards:

```
HashMap<int,String> serviceMap = new HashMap<int,String>
for(String serviceName : serviceNames) {
    // you need to replace serviceIntValue with the actual int value of the service
    serviceMap.put(serviceIntValue,serviceName); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Rajat, this is pretty much what I was looking for. I will update this thread later to show my code.

Comment: @AzIslam This was exactly what I posted in my comment!

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari Thank you for that too! Appreciate both your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Rajat answer is correct. You can also creat a JSON Object, and insert the labels that you want, and after that include it in the hashMap.

JSON example:

```
public static JSONObject constructEHRJSON(int sessionID, String EHR) {
  {
    JSONObject JSONobj = new JSONObject();


    try {

        JSONobj.put("1", sessionID);
        JSONobj.put("2", EHR);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        /
    }
    return JSONobj;

}
```